# Column expands to the right, when pre/code content is too long, but was expecting to make content scrollable

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a simple three column layout:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        {{!-- Left space --}}
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block"></div>

        {{!-- Content --}}
        <div class="col px-5 py-4 post-body">
            {{{contents}}}
        </div>

        {{!-- Right space --}}
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the screen width gets smaller then 768px the middle col takes the full viewport width. That's what I want, so far so good!

But now I have embedded source code within the middle column (part of `{{{contents}}}` that is formated with `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.

```
<pre>
  <code class="hljs csharp">
    {{!-- Some code snippets --}}
  </code>
</pre>
```

If a code line like the one below in the screenshot (`throw new InvalidOperationException("Places to shift must be greater then zero!");`) is too long, the middle column doesn't behave as expected anymore, when further reducing the viewports width.

[image]

As you can see from this screenshots it expands to the right. However I was expecting it to keep its width-ratio and make the code scrollable.

[image]

This is the relevant CSS part from my stylesheet:

```
/* Code blocks */
code.hljs, code {
    border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
  font-size: 0.8125rem; // 13px
  line-height: 21px;
}

code.hljs {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 1em; 
}

code {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `col-md-8 col` so that it only fills the width when the other columns are hidden...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block">Left </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col px-5 py-4 post-body border">
            <pre>
              <code class="hljs csharp">
              </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block">Right </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/D382XygPU5